# Calling Unity C# delegate from unmanaged code in a different thread (Android)

Tags: c#, android, c++, multithreading

I passed a delegate (logging function) to unmanaged code and it works fine, unless it's called from another thread, which is internal to the C++ library.
I read [this](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/), but I can't find any information on what shall I expect when C++ threads are involved. It's definitely threading problem, since delegate works when I call it from the same thread which called unmanaged function from Unity.

**C#**

```
public class SomeClass : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public delegate void LibLogHandler(int a);
    private LibLogHandler handlerDelegate;

    [DllImport ("mylibrary")]
    private static extern bool library_init (string arg1, string arg2, LibLogHandler logHandler);

    public void goNow()
    {
        this.handlerDelegate = new LibLogHandler (this.logHandler);
        bool res = library_init ("someArg1", "someArg2", this.handlerDelegate);
        Debug.Log ("library init: " + res);
    }

    void logHandler(int a)
    {
        Debug.Log ("[library] " + a);
    }
}
```

**C++ header**

```
extern "C" {

    typedef void (*LibLog) (int a);

    bool library_init(const char* arg1, const char* arg3, LibLog libLog);
}
```

**C++ source**

```
static boost::asio::io_service IoService;
static boost::thread aThread;
static boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> ThreadWork;

bool library_init(const char* arg1, const char* arg2, LibLog libLog)
{
#ifdef THREAD_ENABLED
    ThreadWork.reset(new boost::asio::io_service::work(IoService));
    aThread = boost::thread([](){
        IoService.run();
    });        
    IoService.dispatch([libLog]{
        libLog(100);
    });
#else
    libLog(10);
#endif
    return true;
}
```

So, when `THREAD_ENABLED` is defined, application silently crashes with no additional information.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem - [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cbrumme/2003/05/06/asynchronous-operations-pinning/) was useful to understand the peculiarities of callbacks invoked from native plugins. In short, in managed code (C#) one just need to make sure the delegate object is persistent (referenced) for the period while it can be invoked from unmanaged code. **No need to worry** about pinning the memory using `GCHandle`, since managed runtime environment automatically creates an unmanaged stub handle for the delegate object, which maintains its' address regardless of garbage collector operations. This stub handle is passed to the unmanaged function behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Unity doesn't support threading and you can't use it's API in another threads.

Try using

```
bool res;
try{
    res = library_init ("someArg1", "someArg2", this.handlerDelegate);
}catch (System.Exception e){
    Debug.LogError(e.Message);
    throw;
}
```

to get whats wrong with your thread.

EDIT
I wonder if my first statement is true in your case. I think Debug.Log() should be safe. If that's the case you should debug your C++ thread and look why it's crashing.

Comment: what does "Unity doesn't support threading" mean? I don't think that's the case, generally.

Comment: Unity doesn't allow you to use it's API from another threads i.e. if you put something from Unitys API in function and use it in delegate like you do - calling this from another thread probably throws errors.
But like i said in EDIT. Probably in your case it's not the problem. Try debug your C++ code and see why it crashes.